# How can I remove an alert dialog after a AsyncTask has done it's work

Tags: android

I believe I'm doing this correctly, in my activity class I'm calling execute the alert dialog appears and then the data load but the alert dialog never goes away. Here is my AsyncTask code:

Followed by my activity code.

```
public class Worker extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long>{
private Activity ne;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private Handler handler;


public Worker(Handler handler, Activity ne){
this.handler = handler;
this.ne = ne;

}

protected void onPreExecute() {
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ne,"", "Retrieving News Events", true);
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... progress) {

}

protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

    progressDialog.dismiss();
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.os.AsyncTask#doInBackground(Params[])
 */
@Override
protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet get;

    try {
            get = new HttpGet(urls[0].toURI());
        ResponseHandler<String> response = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String responseBody = client.execute(get, response);


        String page = responseBody;

        Bundle data = new Bundle();

        data.putString("page",page);
        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.setData(data);

        handler.sendMessage(msg);

    }
    catch (Throwable t) {
        Log.d("UpdateNews", "PROBLEMS");
    }
return null;
}
```

}

```
public class NewsEvents extends ListActivity{
private URL JSONNewsEvents;
private ArrayList<NewsEvent> neList;
private ArrayList<String> keyWordList;
private Worker worker;
private TextView selection;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
static final int PROGRESS_DIALOG = 0;
public static final String KEYWORDS = "keywords";
private NewsEvents ne;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newsevents);
    ne = this;
    neList = new ArrayList<NewsEvent>();
selection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection);

    try {
    JSONNewsEvents = new URL(getString(R.string.jsonnewsevents));
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

    worker = new Worker(handler, this);

    setListAdapter(new IconicAdapter());
    getKeywords(); 
    worker.execute(JSONNewsEvents);


}

/**
 * @return
 */

public ArrayList<String> getKeywords(){
try {
    InputStream fi = openFileInput(KEYWORDS);

    if (fi!=null) {
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fi);
                keyWordList = (ArrayList<String>) in.readObject();
                in.close();
    }
}
catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
    // that's OK, we probably haven't created it yet
}
catch (Throwable t) {
    Toast
        .makeText(this, "Exception: "+t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        .show();
}
if(keyWordList == null){
    keyWordList = new ArrayList<String>();
    return keyWordList;
}

return keyWordList;
}

public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v,
    int position, long id) {
startFullNewsEvent(neList.get(position));
}

/**
 * @param newsEvent
 */
public void startFullNewsEvent(NewsEvent ne) {
Intent intent = new Intent(this, FullNewsEvent.class);
intent.putExtra("ne", ne);
this.startActivity(intent);
finish();
}



private Handler handler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        String page = msg.getData().getString("page");



        try {  
           JSONArray parseArray = new JSONArray(page);  

           for (int i = 0; i < parseArray.length(); i++) {  
               JSONObject jo = parseArray.getJSONObject(i);  

               String title = jo.getString("title");  

               String body =jo.getString("body");

               String pd = jo.getString("postDate");  

               String id = jo.getString("id");


               NewsEvent ne = new NewsEvent(title, pd , body, id);

               boolean unique = true;
               for(NewsEvent ne0 : neList){
               if(ne.getId().equals(ne0.getId())){
                  unique = false;
               }else{
                   unique = true;
               }
               }

               if(unique == true){
               neList.add(ne);
               }
           }  
          } catch (JSONException e) {  
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
           e.printStackTrace();  
          }
          ne.setListAdapter(new IconicAdapter());

    }
};

public class IconicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NewsEvent> {
IconicAdapter() {
    super(NewsEvents.this, R.layout.rownews, neList);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();

    View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.rownews, parent, false);
    TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.label);
    ImageView image= (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);

    String body = neList.get(position).getBody();
    body.replaceAll("\\<.*?>", "");
    String title = neList.get(position).getTitle();
    for(String s : keyWordList){
        if(body.contains(s) || body.contains(s.toLowerCase()) ||
            title.contains(s) || title.contains(s.toLowerCase())){
        neList.get(position).setInterested(true);
        }
    }

    if(neList.get(position).isInterested() == true){
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
    }


    label.setText(neList.get(position).getTitle());

    return(row);
}
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all change your onPostExecute to include the @Override:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) { 
  progressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

In your class definition include this:

```
public class Worker extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
```

The first parameter is the type of input to the doInBackground method, the second is the type of the input to the onProgressUpdate and the third is the type of the input to the onPostExecute and the result from doInBackground.

It does not look like you are using the input parameter to the doInBackground method, so just change that to Void... and change the return type as well:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... paramArrayOfParams) { ... }
```

Does this help?

Edit:

I saw you had changed your code to use the parameter of the doInBackground, so the first parameter in your class definition is correct. However, try putting Void as the two last parameters. And change the return type of the doInBackground to Void too.

Like this:

```
public class Worker extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Void>{
private Activity ne;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private Handler handler;

public Worker(Handler handler, Activity ne){
  this.handler = handler;
  this.ne = ne;

}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
  progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ne,"", "Retrieving News Events", true);
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... progress) {
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
  progressDialog.dismiss();
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.os.AsyncTask#doInBackground(Params[])
 */
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(URL... urls) {
  HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpGet get;

  try {
        get = new HttpGet(urls[0].toURI());
    ResponseHandler<String> response = new BasicResponseHandler();
    String responseBody = client.execute(get, response);


    String page = responseBody;

    Bundle data = new Bundle();

    data.putString("page",page);
    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.setData(data);

    handler.sendMessage(msg);

  }
  catch (Throwable t) {
    Log.d("UpdateNews", "PROBLEMS");
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Would you mind helping me understand what is going on here? Was it simply because I was not ever returning the correct value?

Comment: Hi. The problem is that if you don't provide the @Override annotation the compiler will not know that you have provided your own implementation of the method. It will then try to invoke the AsyncTask implementation of the method, which obviously does not do what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

You're not overriding the asynctask method correctly. Take a look at an example

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

and note now they declare their asynctask

```
extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long>
```

Comment: I've made those changes to reflect the android dev pages, but my postExecution method is never getting called.

Comment: You only changed how you declare the asynctask. You should study the example further.